# Beautifulsoup not returning values in the first column of HTML table

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a script that open http finds an html table and stores all the values of that table to a csv.

For a second site I wish to copy information from the same script is not working. It fails to produce values for Column one, but still produces the correct values for Column 2 and 3.

I believe this is because on site one the first column looks like:
4216278

where as on the second site the first column looks like:
 4268023

I believe the leading white space before the '4268023' may be the problem?

In the code below col[0] comes back empty, while col[1] and col[2] return the correct values.

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table", border=1)
header = (['Claim_Number', 'Township_Area', 'Date Cancelled_Forfeited'])

records = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')

    Claim_Number = col[0].string
    Township_Area = col[1].string
    Date_Cancelled_Forfeited = col[2].string
    Claim_Cancel = (Claim_Number, Township_Area, Date_Cancelled_Forfeited)
    records.append(Claim_Cancel)
```

## working script

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# go to the MCI Main Menu KENORA Mining Division page
driver.get("http://www.mci.mndm.gov.on.ca/Claims/Cf_Claims/clm_css.cfm?Div=10")

# find first text box
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Claim_View__Claim_Number")

# type in the text box, nothing (could be the claim number for a specific search
inputElement.send_keys("")

# submit the form (click on the search button)
inputElement.submit()

#Read the HTML table with Client info, Store the info, and print to a file.
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table", border=1)
header = (['Claim_Number', 'Township_Area', 'Recorded_Holder', 'Due_Date'])

records = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')

    Claim_Number = col[0].string
    Township_Area = col[1].string
    Recorded_Holder = col[2].string
    Due_Date = col[3].string
    Claim_Att = (Claim_Number, Township_Area, Recorded_Holder, Due_Date)
    records.append(Claim_Att)
with open('MCItest2.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(row for row in records if row)
```

## scripts run to completion, but does not produce a complete csv, column 1 is left blank

```
import csv
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# go to the MCI Main Menu KENORA Mining Division page
driver.get("http://www.mci.mndm.gov.on.ca/Claims/Cf_Claims/clm_cas.cfm?Div=10")

# find first text box
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Claim_Cancellation__Canc_Period")
inputbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Claim_Cancellation__Canc_Period' and @value='90']").click();

# type in the text box, nothing (could be the claim number for a specific search
inputElement.send_keys("")

# submit the form (click on the search button)
inputElement.submit()

#Read the HTML table with Client info, Store the info, and print to a file.
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table", border=1)
header = (['Claim_Number', 'Township_Area', 'Date Cancelled_Forfeited'])

records = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')

    Claim_Number = col[0]' '.string
    Township_Area = col[1].string
    Date_Cancelled_Forfeited = col[2].string
    Claim_Cancel = (Claim_Number, Township_Area, Date_Cancelled_Forfeited)
    records.append(Claim_Cancel)

with open('MCICancel2.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(row for row in records if row)
```

Comment: To aid testing, could you provide a couple of URLs, one that works, and one that does not? :)

Comment: Please see my edited post for the URL's

Comment: I managed to fix the problem i was having. Instead of searching for all 'td', i add a line of code to also search for all 'a' then: link=row.findAll('a') and Claim_Number = link[0].string.strip() this then write the values i was looking for.